# Load and update XML inside the constructor

Tags: c#, beginner, xml, constructor

My requirement is, I need to load the existing xml file from the given path by passing through command line arguments and need to update the xml file from C# code. First time I am working on the C# project. I have done given requirement but need few clarifications and optimization techniques in my code snippet.

```
namespace SchemaChange
{
    class FragmentUpdate
    {
        private String fragmentFileRU;
        private String fragmentFileES;

        private XmlDocument docRU;
        private XmlDocument docES;

        private String fileRU;
        private String fileES;

         public FragmentUpdate(String filename)
         {
            string result = Path.GetFileName(filename);

            fileRU = "PCPE_FRAGMENT_RU.wxs";
            fileES = "PCPE_FRAGMENT_ES.wxs";

         if (result == fileRU.Trim())
            {
                fragmentFileRU = filename;
                docRU = new XmlDocument();
                docRU.Load(fragmentFileRU);
                UpdateFragmentRU();
            }
            else if (result == fileES.Trim())
            {
                fragmentFileES = filename;
                docES = new XmlDocument();
                docES.Load(fragmentFileES);
                UpdateFragmentES();
            }
          }

        private void UpdateFragmentRU()
        {
            string nameSpace = "http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs";

            //Getting document root Element
            XmlElement rootElement = docRU.DocumentElement;

            rootElement.SetAttribute("xmlns", nameSpace);

            XmlElement FragmentElement = (XmlElement)rootElement.GetElementsByTagName("Fragment")[0];
            XmlElement dirRefElement = (XmlElement)FragmentElement.GetElementsByTagName("DirectoryRef")[0];
            XmlElement compElement = (XmlElement)dirRefElement.GetElementsByTagName("Component")[0];
            XmlNodeList fileNodeList = compElement.GetElementsByTagName("File");

            int count = fileNodeList.Count;

            //iterating through the count of nodes
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                XmlElement fileElement = (XmlElement)fileNodeList[i];

                String srcString = fileElement.GetAttribute("src");
                if (srcString != "")
                {
                    //Storing value of src attribute in source attribute
                    fileElement.SetAttribute("Source", srcString);

                    fileElement.RemoveAttribute("src");
                }
            }

            //Saving the document
            docRU.Save(fragmentFileRU);
        }

        private void UpdateFragmentES()
        {
            string nameSpace = "http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs";

            XmlElement rootElement = docES.DocumentElement;

            rootElement.SetAttribute("xmlns", nameSpace);

            XmlElement FragmentElement = (XmlElement)rootElement.GetElementsByTagName("Fragment")[0];
            XmlElement dirRefElement = (XmlElement)FragmentElement.GetElementsByTagName("DirectoryRef")[0];
            XmlElement compElement = (XmlElement)dirRefElement.GetElementsByTagName("Component")[0];
            XmlNodeList fileNodeList = compElement.GetElementsByTagName("File");

            int count = fileNodeList.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                //Getting the File element
                XmlElement fileElement = (XmlElement)fileNodeList[i];

                String srcString = fileElement.GetAttribute("src");
                if (srcString != "")
                {
                    //Storing value of src attribute in source attribute
                    fileElement.SetAttribute("Source", srcString);

                    //removing src attribute
                    fileElement.RemoveAttribute("src");
                }
            }

            //Saving the document
            docES.Save(fragmentFileES);
        }

    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (!(args.Length == 0))
            {
                foreach (string arg in args)
                {
                    FragmentUpdate fragmentUpdate = new FragmentUpdate(arg);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I am passing multiple arguments from the command line. So from the Main() function for each argument I am calling the constructor. Is it the right approach to call the constructor for each command line argument?

From the constructor I am calling the functions (`UpdateFragmentRU();` and `UpdateFragmentES();`). Is it the correct approach or can I call these functions from the Main() function.

Any optimization required in the body of the functions `UpdateFragmentRU()` and `UpdateFragmentES()`.

Can I combine these two functions and optimize?

Please provide your thoughts and suggestions and help my beginning in C#.

Answer (score 1):

With your example there is almost no difference between the two fragments other than the passed in file name format.  However I suspect you want varying behavior between the two `Fragment` types.  You could implement an adapter styled pattern like this:

```
public abstract class Fragment
{
    public const string RUFragmentKey = "PCPE_FRAGMENT_RU.wxs";
    public const string ESFragmentKey = "PCPE_FRAGMENT_ES.wxs";

    protected string fragmentFile;
    protected XmlDocument document;

    public virtual string NameSpace { get; } = "http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs";

    protected Fragment(string fileName)
    {
        string result = Path.GetFileName(fileName).Trim();

        fragmentFile = fileName;
        document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load(fragmentFile);
        Update();
    }

    public static Fragment Create(string fileName)
    {
        fileName = fileName.Trim();
        switch (fileName)
        {
            case RUFragmentKey:
                return new RUFragment(fileName);
            case ESFragmentKey:
                return new ESFragment(fileName);
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException($"Fragment type '{fileName}' not supported.");
        }
    }

    public virtual void Update()
    {
        XmlElement rootElement = document.DocumentElement;
        rootElement.SetAttribute("xmlns", NameSpace);

        XmlElement FragmentElement = (XmlElement)rootElement.GetElementsByTagName("Fragment")[0];
        XmlElement dirRefElement = (XmlElement)FragmentElement.GetElementsByTagName("DirectoryRef")[0];
        XmlElement compElement = (XmlElement)dirRefElement.GetElementsByTagName("Component")[0];
        XmlNodeList fileNodeList = compElement.GetElementsByTagName("File");

        for (int i = 0; i < fileNodeList.Count; i++)
        {
            //Getting the File element
            XmlElement fileElement = (XmlElement)fileNodeList[i];

            string srcString = fileElement.GetAttribute("src");
            if (srcString != "")
            {
                //Storing value of src attribute in source attribute
                fileElement.SetAttribute("Source", srcString);

                //removing src attribute
                fileElement.RemoveAttribute("src");
            }
        }

        //Saving the document
        document.Save(fragmentFile);
    }
}
```

`Update` is virtual so derived classes can use specific implementation if needed via override.

Since there is currently zero difference between the two, the initial subclasses are plain:

```
public class RUFragment : Fragment
{
    internal RUFragment(string fileName)
        : base(fileName) { }

    // Override functionality and add implementation details
}

public class ESFragment : Fragment
{
    internal ESFragment(string fileName)
        : base(fileName) { }

    // Override functionality and add implementation details
}
```

So the main function could be something along the lines of:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (!(args.Length == 0))
    {
        foreach (string arg in args)
        {
            Fragment fragment = Fragment.Create(arg);
        }
    }
}
```

It's impossible to know what your intent is, but maybe this will get you started in a useful direction.

Comment: 1. Why to pass string fileName to both the functions "Fragment" and "Create" 2. I understood that from Fragment() constructor we are calling update() function and it is updating xml data for both the files. Then what is the point of checking the filename in create() function. I also didn't understand what Create() function will do 3. And also what we are doing in public class RUFragment : Fragment function.

Comment: 1.  That is the private constructor on `Fragment`.  I added it in this example because it forces a constructor onto the subclasses.  So on `RUFragment` and `ESFragment` now the constructor with a filename is required.

Comment: 2.  `Fragment.Create` is a static factory initialization method.  You want to create a `Fragment` based on the filename, so you let the static `Fragment.Create` method determine specifically which type it returns.

Comment: 3.  Since your original functionality was identical between the two fragment types, you can see that no implementation details are needed in the `RUFragment` and `ESFragment` classes.  This should change per your requirements, since I assume you have a logical reason for separating these out in the first place.